# Databricks: how to convert Spark dataframe under %python to dataframe under %r

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a Dataframe in %python environment, and try to use that in %r environment.

How can I convert a spark dataframe under %python to %r ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not even worth trying. The idiomatic way is to register temporary view and let metastore do the rest. In Python:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("some_name")
```

in R:

```
sql("REFRESH TABLE some_name")
df <- sql("SELECT * FROM some_name")
```